# How do I make apport file a bug report automatically?

Tags: bug-reporting, apport

In 12.04 i get alot of `Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error` popups
I found this tutorial on [how to get rid of internal system error(webupd8)](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-get-rid-of-internal-system-error.html).

It disables apport. What i want is that apport automatically reports the bug
and not "bug" me with further popups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my personal experience, just filing a report with the name of the package and the trace is usually insufficient. You will be asked to provide further information such as the context in which the bug occurred and an outline on how to reproduce it. This will further help confirming, triaging and eventually solving the bug.

The bottom-line is some information cannot be retrieved "automatically" and user input will always be needed to improve the reporting quality.