# "System Problem Detected Apport" - How to send reports by default?

Tags: 14.04, apport

I use a lot of wine apps that sometimes cause UI problems. Is there anyway I can configure Ubuntu to send these reports by default instead of it prompting me every time and me entering the root password each time?

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153504/how-do-i-make-apport-file-a-bug-report-automatically) article from 2012 and was wondering if this paradigm still stands.

System:
Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Kernel:
3.13.0-35-generic